# Python output from twitter search api to txt

Tags: python, twitter

I cant find a way to save the output from twitter search api in a txt. The programming language I use is Python and I am a beginner. Can smn help me. Thx in adv.

> ```
> import urllib
> import json
>
> search = urllib.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q="+"android&rpp=100")
>
> dict = json.loads(search.read())
> for result in dict["results"]:
>    print  "#", result["text"],"\n"
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about redirecting the output `mypythonscript.py > /where/to/save.txt`

Or just save it in python (using your code):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib
import json
import codecs

search = urllib.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q="+"android&rpp=100")

with codecs.open('/tmp/fap.txt', 'a+', 'utf8') as f:
    dict = json.loads(search.read())
    for result in dict["results"]:
        f.write('# %s\n' % result["text"])
```